# multiple inputs for filtering column values

Tags: python, pandas

quick question:

I want to filter df columns with multiple like statements:

```
      line amount#1    line amount#2    line amount#3
--  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
 0               95              nan            nan
 2              260              nan            nan
 4              260               30             12.5
            woef#1            tax#2             tax#3
--  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
 0               95              nan            nan
 2              260              nan            nan
 4              260               30             12.5
```

`dftaxitemscount = dfresult.filter(like='quantity')` works for quantity. However not when multiple arguments are given:

```
dftaxitemscount = dfresult.filter(like='quantity', 'tax')
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

How to do this for multiple inputs?

Comment: `dfresult.filter(regex='quantity|tax')`?

Comment: Yes this is a nice one! Thanks